# VBA Save Sheet as New Workbook to Desktop (Regardless of User)

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you for helping me out! I'm trying to (1) create a new workbook (2) copy & paste one sheet to the new workbook and (3) save that new workbook to desktop, regardless of user, as an .xlsx file. The coding below is saving the file somewhere but I don't know where or how to change it to desktop. Any suggestions?

```
*cName = "TEST FILE"
Sheets("Random").Select
Set wb = Workbooks.Item(1)
Set ws = Sheets("Random")
filename = cName & "-" & ActiveSheet.Name
Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add
wbnew.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Random").Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)
wbnew.Close*
```

Comment: You haven't saved the file anywhere. Copying a worksheet to a new workbook is best done with e.g. 1st line: `ws.Copy`, 2nd line: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, xlOpenXMLWorkbook`. The path to the desktop is usually `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\DeskTop"` or `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive\DeskTop"`.